# Where/When should I create a table that is the basis of my program?

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, deployment

I'm developing a desktop java program that takes advantage of an SQLite database to restore some data. I now how to create the database and create my table :

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mokvoc.db");
stmt = c.createStatement();
String sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY " + ...
```

## problem

The problem is that I want to execute this statement just **once** through the whole life time of the program and specially at the **first time** that the program runs ***or*** during the **installation step**. Please tell me how can I perform this and is it required to add a new JFrame or I don't now sth like that?

Comment: u can do one thing check that table exist or not in the db, if exist then leave otherwise create it

Comment: Please don't mistake,I don't want to check for it's existence every time! Obviously this is not efficient at all. I want to add it somewhere at the begining and then I'm convenient that it exists.

Comment: We dnt knw how ur code runs, u can put it wherever u thing that it will run only once.

Answer (score 3):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), *easy management of common resources using extensions..*

That last one is good for deploying the DB API itself.  It might be used across a number of different applications.

Populating the DB would best be done as part of the `..` above, as seen  in the extension installer service.  This is run once on install, and again on uninstall.

> The [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html) is used by an extension installer to communicate with the JNLP Client. It provides the following type of functionality:
>
> - Access to prefered installation location, and other information about the JNLP Client
> - Manipulation of the JNLP Client's download screen
> - Methods for updating the JNLP Client with the installed code

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on your processes...for example, **depending** on you installation process, you could execute a specific piece of code which builds the database and tables when the application is installed.  Many installers do provide the means to do this, but are typically focused on the platform they are designed for (such as executing a .exe on Windows)

OR

You could, when the application is launched, do a check for the existence of the database/tables and do a "first" run setup process

OR

You could pre-create the database and tables and package it as part of the installer...

Comment: The third solution seems great, would you please guide me how to do this with an SQLite databse?

Comment: Personally, I would a simple tool that did just this, creates the database, creates the tables as you want them to be and then place the resulting database within the context of you application, based on your requirements.  This makes it very simple then to wrap a installer around it based on your needs

Comment: Now this raises another question for me, Assume that I export my program in jar and put in 'C:\Prog' and put my DB 'database.db' into 'C:\Prog\DB' how to connect to it in my program?

Comment: should be created, intialized, used and closed (for periodical updates to the Swing GUI) from WorkersThread, more about  WorkersThread is in Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing

Comment: You want to use a relative path within the JDBC connection string, something like `DB/database.db` for example, this way, it doesn't matter where you put your application

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the database.
2. Fetch database metadata from the connection.
3. You can query the available tables from the database metadata. If you don't find your tables your application is running for the first time. Initialize the database - create tables, insert seed data etc.